# Backup and recovery from oracle 10g to sqlite

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

How to take back up of database from oracle 10g and recover it to sqlite?

Can we take back up of tables only and recover them ?

If you don't know then please tell me whether it is possible or not???

Answer (score 1):

wow ... calling that backup and recovery ....
If you want, you can copy data from Oracle to sqllite, or whatever database system you like. Looking at [sqlite - Importing Files](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles) I think a good option would be to generate csv files containing the data, a file per table.

You can use sqlplus to generate csv files and many methods to do that are described on the internet.

If this needs to be done in a consistent way, make sure that there are no other connections allowed, or that the database runs in read only mode during the csv file generation, otherwise you are pretty sure ending up with an inconsistent dataset in your target database.